# union can't contain an object that has a virtual function

Tags: c++, unions

**Code:**

```
struct A{
    int a;
    virtual void f(){}
};
union B{
    A ob;
};
```

**Compile-time Error:**

```
C:\to\main.cpp|9|error: member 'A B::ob' with constructor not allowed in union|
C:\to\main.cpp|9|error: member 'A B::ob' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

**c++03 Standard:**

> An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a
>   non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4),
>   or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a
>   member of a union, nor can an array of such  objects. If a union
>   contains a static data member, or a member of reference type, the
>   program is ill-formed.

The standard doesn't say anything about an object of a class with a virtual function, and from the error, the compiler complain about constructor and copy-assignment operator which I didn't use. so is this a compiler bug ? Im using gcc .

Comment: By non-trivial, think POD (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)

Comment: @Benj I dont know what non-trivial mean, but im sure it's not POD since it A  can have a base class, in this I dont get an Error, so union member data doesn't have to be a POD.

Comment: If you check out the article I referenced you'll see that unions are mentioned specifically with regard to POD.  Also it's possible for a class to be POD.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The implicitly declared default constructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment operator for that struct are non-trivial because it has a `virtual` function, so you've broken those requirements.

> A constructor is *trivial* if it is an implicitly-declared default constructor and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - [...]
>
> A copy constructor for class `X` is *trivial* if it is implicitly declared and if
>
> - class `X` has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - [...]
>
> A copy assignment operator for class `X` is *trivial* if it is implicitly declared and if
>
> - class `X` has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - [...]

The C++11 quote is similar (it just includes move constructors and assignment operators) but C++11 does not have the same requirement on members of unions.

Answer (score 0):

Use C++11 if you can, it doesn't contain such constraint

Comment: It has other constraints, making it extremely hard instead of impossible.